# invalid value for Integer(): "''" in pagination of rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I get a pagination error like as follows.
invalid value for Integer(): "''"
In my controller I use the code:

`@articles = Article.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)`

In the index method. What is the error?

Comment: What you're getting in your params, can you show?

Comment: I add only the above comment in controller and in view page, <div class="pagination" align="center">
  <span class="previous_page disabled">Previous</span> 
  <em class="current">1</em> 
  <a rel="next" href="/articles?page=2">2</a> 
  <a href="/articles?page=3">3</a> 
  <a href="/articles?page=4">4</a> 
  <a class="next_page" rel="next" href="/articles?page=2">Next</a>
</div>
 <%= will_paginate @articles %>

Comment: I'm not add any other code to my app.Rather than that what want to do to overcome the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this

```
@articles = Article.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: sorry Mr.Kumar, I get the same error.What can I do?

Comment: Hey thanks buddy..It works.I make a mistake in routing url. Once again  great thanks to save my time.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you figured it out yourself. :)